# how to fix error i am not getting requested ticket id

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog

I am working on ticket system in which i am trying to implement modal which is requested ticket status for change

here is view code

```
 <button style="color:#fff; background:#8c000d" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#status-modal2" class="btn btn-default login-button center"><a href="javascript:;" data-id="{{$ticket->id}}">Update Status</a></button>
```

here is modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="status-modal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            {{Form::open(['url'=>['tickets', $ticket->id], 
                'class'=>'defaultForm','method' =>'post'])}}
                <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Update Ticket Status</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <select>
                            <option value="closed" {{($ticket->status) == 'closed'? 'selected': ''}}>Closed</option>
                            <option value="job in process" {{($ticket->status) == 'job in process'? '': ''}}>Job In Process</option>
                            <option value="others" {{($ticket->status) == 'others'? '': ''}}>Others</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="basic-button red" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="basic-button">Update</button>
                </div>
                {{Form::close()}}
            </div>
```

here is route

```
Route::post('/tickets/{id}','TicketsController@updateTicketsHome');
```

my expected output is requested ticket updated should be change

i tried to implement myself but i am getting either first ticket id or last id how do i do when user click single ticket it ask for status change of clicked ticket

Comment: did you get a chance to research about it?

Comment: Trying appending the ticket variable in url section as url=>['ticket/'.$ticket->id]

Answer (score 1):

Name your route using the `name()` method,

```
Route::post('/tickets/{id}','TicketsController@updateTicketsHome')->name('tickets.update');
```

That way, you can reference it by a name. You then specify a route to send your form to, instead of sending it to an `url`, by changing your form to

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['tickets.update', $ticket->id], 
               'class' => 'defaultForm',
               'method' => 'post']) }}
```

Comment: Then you need to check your controller, debug it by checking the incoming values.

Comment: i checked every time it takes last id of ticket table

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest an alternative solution.
Change your route in `web.php`

```
 Route::post('/tickets/{id}','TicketsController@updateTicketsHome')->name('ticket.update');
```

In your `view`

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('ticket.update', ['id' => $ticket->id]) }}" >
```

Comment: i changed as per your say but i am getting another error which is tokenmissmatch error

Comment: add {{csrf_token()}} in form